# update stock after order placed in laravel php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel i need to do update stock after order placed from a client/user app i used Http api for that but when i added stock update code in Http api file i'm getting `internal server error` in user app and also order is no placing if i remove stock update code from Http api it is taking order without error and `stock update` and the error i'm getting `live.ERROR: Undefined variable: total_stock {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: total_stock at /home/ttrr/domain/folder/app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/OrderController.php:280) [stacktrace]`

Here is my stock update code

```
$type = $c['variation'][0]['type'];
$var_store = [];
foreach (json_decode($product['variations'], true) as $var) {
    if ($type == $var['type']) {
        $var['stock'] -= $c['quantity'];
    }
    array_push($var_store, $var);
}
Product::where(['id' => $product['id']])->update([
               'variations'  => json_encode($var_store),
               'total_stock' => $product['total_stock'] - $c['quantity'],
             ]);
```

Here is my ordercontroll.php

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function track_order(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'order_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => Helpers::error_processor($validator)], 403);
        }
        $order = Order::with(['restaurant', 'delivery_man.rating'])->withCount('details')->where(['id' => $request['order_id'], 'user_id' => $request->user()->id])->first();
        if($order)
        {
            $order['restaurant'] = $order['restaurant']?Helpers::restaurant_data_formatting($order['restaurant']):$order['restaurant'];   
            $order['delivery_address'] = $order['delivery_address']?json_decode($order['delivery_address']):$order['delivery_address'];   
            $order['delivery_man'] = $order['delivery_man']?Helpers::deliverymen_data_formatting([$order['delivery_man']]):$order['delivery_man'];
            unset($order['details']);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => [
                    ['code' => 'schedule_at', 'message' => trans('messages.not_found')]
                ]
            ], 404);
        }
        return response()->json($order, 200);
    }

    public function place_order(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'order_amount' => 'required',
            'payment_method'=>'required|in:cash_on_delivery,digital_payment',
            'order_type' => 'required|in:take_away,delivery',
            'restaurant_id' => 'required',
            'distance' => 'required_if:order_type,delivery',
            'address' => 'required_if:order_type,delivery',
            'longitude' => 'required_if:order_type,delivery',
            'latitude' => 'required_if:order_type,delivery',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => Helpers::error_processor($validator)], 403);
        }


        $coupon = null;
        $delivery_charge = null;
        $schedule_at = $request->schedule_at?\Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->schedule_at):now();
        if($request->schedule_at && $schedule_at < now())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => [
                    ['code' => 'order_time', 'message' => trans('messages.you_can_not_schedule_a_order_in_past')]
                ]
            ], 406);
        }
        $restaurant = Restaurant::with('discount')->whereTime('opening_time','<=',$schedule_at->format('H:i'))->whereTime('closeing_time','>=',$schedule_at->format('H:i'))->where('id', $request->restaurant_id)->first();
        if(!$restaurant)
        {
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => [
                    ['code' => 'order_time', 'message' => trans('messages.restaurant_is_closed_at_order_time')]
                ]
            ], 406);
        }
        if($request->schedule_at && !$restaurant->schedule_order)
        {
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => [
                    ['code' => 'schedule_at', 'message' => trans('messages.schedule_order_not_available')]
                ]
            ], 406);
        }

        if ($request['coupon_code']) {
            $coupon = Coupon::active()->where(['code' => $request['coupon_code']])->first();
            if (isset($coupon)) {
                $staus = CouponLogic::is_valide($coupon, $request->user()->id ,$request['restaurant_id']);
                if($staus==407)
                {
                    return response()->json([
                        'errors' => [
                            ['code' => 'coupon', 'message' => trans('messages.coupon_expire')]
                        ]
                    ], 407);
                }
                else if($staus==406)
                {
                    return response()->json([
                        'errors' => [
                            ['code' => 'coupon', 'message' => trans('messages.coupon_usage_limit_over')]
                        ]
                    ], 406);
                }
                else if($staus==404)
                {
                    return response()->json([
                        'errors' => [
                            ['code' => 'coupon', 'message' => trans('messages.not_found')]                            
                        ]
                    ], 404);
                }
                if($coupon->coupon_type == 'free_delivery')
                {
                    $delivery_charge = 0;
                    $coupon = null;
                }
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'errors' => [
                        ['code' => 'coupon', 'message' => 'not found!']
                    ]
                ], 401);
            }
        }
        $per_km_shipping_charge = (float)BusinessSetting::where(['key' => 'per_km_shipping_charge'])->first()->value;
        $minimum_shipping_charge = (float)BusinessSetting::where(['key' => 'minimum_shipping_charge'])->first()->value;
        $original_delivery_charge = ($request->distance * $per_km_shipping_charge > $minimum_shipping_charge) ? $request->distance * $per_km_shipping_charge : $minimum_shipping_charge;
        if($request['order_type'] != 'take_away' && !$restaurant->free_delivery && $delivery_charge == null)
        {
            $delivery_charge = ($request->distance * $per_km_shipping_charge > $minimum_shipping_charge) ? $request->distance * $per_km_shipping_charge : $minimum_shipping_charge;
        }

        if($request->latitude && $request->longitude)
        {
            $point = new Point($request->latitude,$request->longitude);
            $zone = Zone::where('id', $restaurant->zone_id)->contains('coordinates', $point)->first();
            if(!$zone)
            {
                $errors = [];
                array_push($errors, ['code' => 'coordinates', 'message' => trans('messages.out_of_coverage')]);
                return response()->json([
                    'errors' => $errors
                ], 403);
            }
        }

        $address = [
            'contact_person_name' => $request->contact_person_name?$request->contact_person_name:$request->user()->f_name.' '.$request->user()->f_name,
            'contact_person_number' => $request->contact_person_number?$request->contact_person_number:$request->user()->phone,
            'address_type' => $request->address_type?$request->address_type:'Delivery',
            'address' => $request->address,
            'longitude' => (string)$request->longitude,
            'latitude' => (string)$request->latitude,
        ];

        $total_addon_price = 0;
        $product_price = 0;
        $restaurant_discount_amount = 0;

        $order_details = [];
        $order = new Order();
        $order->id = 100000 + Order::all()->count() + 1;
        $order->user_id = $request->user()->id;
        $order->order_amount = $request['order_amount'];
        $order->payment_status = 'unpaid';
        $order->order_status = $request['payment_method']=='digital_payment'?'failed':'pending';
        $order->coupon_code = $request['coupon_code'];
        $order->payment_method = $request->payment_method;
        $order->transaction_reference = null;
        $order->order_note = $request['order_note'];
        $order->order_type = $request['order_type'];
        $order->restaurant_id = $request['restaurant_id'];
        $order->delivery_charge = $delivery_charge??0;
        $order->original_delivery_charge = $original_delivery_charge;
        $order->delivery_address = json_encode($address);
        $order->schedule_at = $schedule_at;
        $order->scheduled = $request->schedule_at?1:0;
        $order->otp = rand(1000, 9999);
        $order->pending = now();
        $order->created_at = now();
        $order->updated_at = now();
        foreach ($request['cart'] as $c) {
            /*foreach (json_decode($product['variations'], true) as $var) {
                if ($type == $var['type'] && $var['stock'] < $c['quantity']) {
                    $validator->getMessageBag()->add('stock', 'Stock is insufficient! available stock ' . $var['stock']);
                }
            }*/

            if ($c['item_campaign_id'] != null) {
                $product = ItemCampaign::find($c['item_campaign_id']);
                if ($product) {
                 $type = $c['variation'][0]['type'];
                 foreach (json_decode($product['variations'], true) as $var) {
                    if ($type == $var['type'] && $var['stock'] < $c['quantity']) {
                        $validator->getMessageBag()->add('stock', 'Stock is insufficient! available stock ' . $var['stock']);
                    }
                    else {
                        $price = $product['price'];
                    }
                  }
                    /*if (count(json_decode($product['variations'], true)) > 0) {
                        $price = Helpers::variation_price($product, json_encode($c['variation']));
                    }*/ 
                    $product->tax = $restaurant->tax;
                    $product = Helpers::product_data_formatting($product);
                    $addon_data = Helpers::calculate_addon_price(\App\Models\AddOn::whereIn('id',$c['add_on_ids'])->get(), $c['add_on_qtys']);
                    $or_d = [
                        'food_id' => null,
                        'item_campaign_id' => $c['item_campaign_id'],
                        'food_details' => json_encode($product),
                        'quantity' => $c['quantity'],
                        'price' => $price,
                        'tax_amount' => Helpers::tax_calculate($product, $price),
                        'discount_on_food' => Helpers::product_discount_calculate($product, $price, $restaurant),
                        'discount_type' => 'discount_on_product',
                        'variant' => json_encode($c['variant']),
                        'is_stock_decreased'  => 1,
                        'variation' => json_encode($c['variation']),
                        'add_ons' => json_encode($addon_data['addons']),
                        'total_add_on_price' => $addon_data['total_add_on_price'],
                        'created_at' => now(),
                        'updated_at' => now()
                    ];
                    $order_details[] = $or_d;
                    $total_addon_price += $or_d['total_add_on_price'];
                    $product_price += $price*$or_d['quantity'];
                    $restaurant_discount_amount += $or_d['discount_on_food']*$or_d['quantity'];
                } else {
                    return response()->json([
                        'errors' => [
                            ['code' => 'campaign', 'message' => 'not found!']
                        ]
                    ], 401);
                }
            } else {
                $product = Food::find($c['food_id']);
                if ($product) {
                    if (count(json_decode($product['variations'], true)) > 0) {
                        $price = Helpers::variation_price($product, json_encode($c['variation']));
                    } else {
                        $price = $product['price'];
                    }
                    $product->tax = $restaurant->tax;
                    $product = Helpers::product_data_formatting($product);
                    $addon_data = Helpers::calculate_addon_price(\App\Models\AddOn::whereIn('id',$c['add_on_ids'])->get(), $c['add_on_qtys']);
                    $or_d = [
                        'food_id' => $c['food_id'],
                        'item_campaign_id' => null,
                        'food_details' => json_encode($product),
                        'quantity' => $c['quantity'],
                        'price' => $price,
                        'is_stock_decreased'  => 1,
                        'tax_amount' => Helpers::tax_calculate($product, $price),
                        'discount_on_food' => Helpers::product_discount_calculate($product, $price, $restaurant),
                        'discount_type' => 'discount_on_product',
                        'variant' => json_encode($c['variant']),
                        'variation' => json_encode($c['variation']),
                        'add_ons' => json_encode($addon_data['addons']),
                        'total_add_on_price' => $addon_data['total_add_on_price'],
                        'created_at' => now(),
                        'updated_at' => now()
                    ];
                    //stock update code 
                    $type = $c['variation'][0]['type'];
                    $var_store = [];
                    foreach (json_decode($product['variations'], true) as $var) {
                    if ($type == $var['type']) {
                        $var['stock'] -= $c['quantity'];
                    }
                    array_push($var_store, $var);
                  }
                Product::where(['id' => $product['id']])->update([
                    'variations'  => json_encode($var_store),
                    'total_stock' => $product['total_stock'] - $c['quantity'],
                ]);

                    DB::table('order_details')->insert($or_d);
                    $total_addon_price += $or_d['total_add_on_price'];
                    $product_price += $price*$or_d['quantity'];
                    $restaurant_discount_amount += $or_d['discount_on_food']*$or_d['quantity'];
                    $order_details[] = $or_d;
                } else {
                    return response()->json([
                        'errors' => [
                            ['code' => 'food', 'message' => 'not found!']
                        ]
                    ], 401);
                }
            }
```

And tried mentioning variable like this `'total_stock' =>$total_stock` but still not working

Comment: Have you specified the ``total_stock`` variable in ``Product`` entity?

Comment: Are you sure you have shared all of the relevant code? Is this the only line that references `total_stock`? `'total_stock' => $product['total_stock'] - $c['quantity'],`

Comment: @Vince how to mention product I'd where total_stock should update

Comment: @manuhegde I don't understand your reply. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'm saying this ```Product::where(['id' => $product['id']])->update([
               'variations'  => json_encode($var_store),
               'total_stock' => $product['total_stock'] - $c['quantity'],
             ]); ```  how to add this in here ```total_stock? 'total_stock' => $product['total_stock'] - $c['quantity'],```